# Setting values in new List object to values in existing List

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to populate fields in one list with values from another list. I'm having trouble figuring out how to avoid the Argument Out of Range exception in the new List. I tried initializing the size of the new list to myObjectA.Count but then read that this won't actually initialize the list of that size like an array would. I'm a little stuck and was hoping for some assistance. Thanks

```
 List<objectA> myObjectA  =_GetList(id);
 List<objectB> myObjectB = new List<objectB>();


 for (var i=0; i < myObjectA.Count; i++)
 {
      myObjectB[i].Comments = myObjectA[i].Comments;
 }
```

Comment: Are you actually adding any `ObjectB`s to the list `myObjectB`? In your code snippet above `myObjectB` is empty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `myObjectB` is an **empty list**. You are looping through the `myObjectA` list which might have one more item and in the first iteration of the loop it will try to execute code like

```
myObjectB[0].Comments = myObjectA[0].Comments;
```

Which will crash because there is no items in the `myObjectB` list and you are trying to access the first item(zeroth index), hence getting the Out of Range exception ! specifically the **Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.** exception

Assuming both `objectB` and `objectA` has `Comments` property of same type, you can loop through the `myObjectA` list and for each item, create a new `objectB` object and add to the list (which was originally initalized as the empty list) using the `Add` method.

```
List<objectB> myObjectB = new List<objectB>();
for (var i=0; i < myObjectA.Count; i++)
{
    var b = new objectB();  //create the object
    b.Comments = myObjectA[i].Comments;  // map the property values
    myObjectB.Add(b);  //add the object to the list
}
```

The above foreach code can be made to a one liner with LINQ projection

```
var bList = myObjectA.Select(x => new objectB { Comments = x.Comments }).ToList();
```

The variable `bList` will be a list of `objectB` objects.

Answer (score 2):

You can do like this :

```
for (var i = 0; i < myObjectA.Count; i++)
{
      myObjectB.Add(new objectB()
      {
           Comments = myObjectA[i].Comments
      });
}
```

This way, with each iteration it'll add new `objectB` into `myObjectB` list.

With `Linq`, you can shorten your code :

```
myObjectB = myObjectA.Select(x => new objectB { Comments = x.Comments }).ToList();
```

Comment: This also worked nicely. Wish I could mark both as the answer. :)